# Select changes do not affect ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I've been having a look some related post with no success in my case even having the same code.

I have a **select** like the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="col">Visible: </label>
   <select class="custom-select" id="col"
           ng-options="visible as visible.name for visible in visibility"
           ng-model="selected_visible_product"
           ng-change="update_product_list()"
           style="width:140px">
           <option>Visibility...</option>
   </select>
   <label>{{selected_visible_product}}</label>
</div>
```

Visibility array is defined like this:

```
$scope.visibility = [{ID:0, name:'Disabled'},{ID:1, name:'Enabled'}];
```

First time a print the value of **selected_visible_product**, it shows the correct value, but when I change the select option, `update_product_list()` print again the actual value of **selected_visible_product** and it shows the same.

This is what update_product_list() prints (na matter what you choose):

> Object {ID: 0, name: "Disabled", $$hashKey: "object:140"}

`update_product_list()` just print in console the value of **selected_visible_product**

```
$scope.update_product_list = function() {
    console.info($scope.selected_visible_product.ID);
}
```

What's happening?

UPDATE:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more code/create a fiddle or a snippet?

Comment: You are not much clear about what you wanr ? and what `update_product_list()` do ?

Comment: Post the code for js please. `update_product_list()`, `update `, `saveRow`

Comment: I tthink you have ng-options wrong.  try,   `ng-options="visible.ID as visible.name for visible in visibility"`

Comment: @Sravan That might be, but that doesn't cause the issue mentioned

Comment: @Sravan I changed as you mentioned but the output still the same.

Comment: @domindal, pls change the `ng-repeat` and tell if the issue still persists.

Comment: well i think, in your case some how on change of dropdown , the value of `selected_visible_product` is been changed while or before the call of `update_product_list()` method , so for proper answer , you have to provide more code to check.

Comment: Now, I'm realizing that selected_visible_product is not shown when I print $scope in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet with your code. It seems to be working fine. What's different?

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', function mycontroller($scope) {
    $scope.visibility = [{ID:0, name:'Disabled'},{ID:1, name:'Enabled'}];
    $scope.update_product_list = function() {
     alert($scope.selected_visible_product.name);
     }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="col">Visible: </label>
   <select class="custom-select" id="col"
           ng-options="visible as visible.name for visible in visibility"
           ng-model="selected_visible_product"
           ng-change="update_product_list()"
           style="width:140px">
           <option>Visibility...</option>
   </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, what I print is selected_visible_product

Comment: Updated. Sorry I made a mistake.

Comment: Added a snippet. Seems to be working fine. Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Incredible. It's exactly the same code and for me not working.

Comment: Hmmm... that's highly weird. Maybe change the version of Angular you're using? Chances are there must be something really obvious that you're missing

Comment: I have made many changes and read angularjs documentation and nothing. ng-model never change in select changes. I'm using the latest release of angular, 1.5.8. If you set selected_visible_product, it changes perfectly, but when change the option in browser, the model never change to its actual value

Comment: Now, a very estrange thing... I have placed a span tag in the HTML with {{selected_visible_product}} in it and it displays changes but the function in ng-change do not. it's like variables were different.

Comment: All angular functionality works fine except such detail and the controller is at the top level of the DOM.

Comment: Why don't you add selected_visible_product = false; in your controller as initialization?

Comment: Finally I solved (as a tricky) by passing selected_visible_product as an argument to update_product_list() and within the function triggered on change, I update the value within the controller. Thanks for your time.